# How to play a portrait video in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

I'm trying to play a portrait video in Flutter, fitting the height and width of the screen in my app using [chewie](https://pub.dev/packages/chewie). The landscape mode works fine however it doesn't seem to fit in portrait and there is some sort of odd padding at the left and right side. I've spent hours trying different dependencies but nothing has worked. How do I fetch the aspect ratio that will fit the video according to the size of my screen vertically?

This is my code:

```
class FullVideo extends StatefulWidget {
  final String videoSrc;
  FullVideo({this.videoSrc});

  @override
  _FullVideoState createState() => _FullVideoState();
}

class _FullVideoState extends State<FullVideo> {
  VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController;

  Future<bool> initVideoPlayer() async {
    await videoPlayerController.initialize();
    return videoPlayerController.value.initialized;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(File(widget.videoSrc));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    videoPlayerController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: initVideoPlayer(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Chewie(
                controller: ChewieController(
                    videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
                    aspectRatio: videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
                    autoPlay: true),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        });
  }
}
```

This is what the output looks like:
[image]